# Is it possible to have a redundant S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We use S3 for static file hosting. Is it possible to set it up as redundant? I don't want to rely only on one zone in case anything brokens.

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK AWS don't provide replication services, if you want it you'll have to implement it by yourself.

Comment: @alfasin AWS does provide S3 replication. See my answer.

Comment: @MarkB if I understand correctly the replication is a bucket-replication not across zone/region.

Comment: @alfasin it is called "Cross region replication" because it replicates across regions. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/crr.html

Comment: @MarkB hmmm didn't know about this option, nice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amazon S3 buckets are regional-level services. Data is replicated automatically across multiple Availability Zones.

So, if you wish to have redundancy across **Availability Zones**, it is done for you automatically.

If you wish to have redundancy across regions, you might be able to use Amazon CloudFront and/or Amazon Route 53.

Answer (score -1):

Its not possible to have redundant bucket names in aws....all the bucket names in aws are unique.